# What is the PowerShell Equivilant of `curl -L https://unpkg.com/@pnpm/self-installer | node`?

Tags: powershell, curl, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using [GitLab.com](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/README.html) with a Windows OS runner, so we commonly use PowerShell in place of Bash for scripting steps in the console. I'm trying to use [pnpm](https://pnpm.js.org/docs/en/continuous-integration.html) and the examples they give suggest the following

```
$ curl -L https://unpkg.com/@pnpm/self-installer | node
$ install pnpm
```

What's the PowerShell version of the above curl requests piped into `node`?

I've been trying both [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-RestMethod?view=powershell-6) and using the `curl` alias from within PowerShell, like

```
PS> curl https://unpkg.com/@pnpm/self-installer | node
```

but have been getting

> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Also from the curl docs, I know [--location](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L) is needed.

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-RestMethod?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 not too helpful. If I knew powershell I wouldn't ask the question. I already had the docs open, as I've already read https://superuser.com/questions/344927/powershell-equivalent-of-curl . If you also don't know the answer don't be negative and down vote me, stick around and learn from what people post.

Comment: Your question is a bad one and shows no effort.  It's basically "translate this command into destination lang plz"

Comment: I think this kind of response is why PowerShell folks who have mad skills and who could offer a lot to this community, end up with a bad wrap. I'll try to beef up my question I guess, to "prove I'm worthy of your help".

Comment: It's not about being worthy of my help, it's about showing you did any work rather than using SO to do your job for you.  You will find this is true in any of the tags.  Could you post your full exception message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a best practice within scripts, I'd suggest explicitly using the parameter names and passing the correct type rather than letting the interpreter coerce for you (`Uri` takes a `System.Uri` and `System` is imported to PowerShell as a default):

```
$uri = [Uri]'https://unpkg.com/@pnpm/self-installer'
$js = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri
```

The reason for your syntax error? the `@` symbol is special in PowerShell for a feature called Splatting.

When I ran the above, it spit out the contents of a `js` script to my console.  It can then be assumed `node` takes cli, piped input and is in your PATH:

```
$js | node
```

Another assumption is you have an `install` in your PATH or the script creates some kind of interactive terminal:

```
$ install pnpm
```

`--location` isn't necessary here since `Invoke-RestMethod` will follow a redirect up to 5 hops by default (this can be configured with `MaximumRedirection`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on breaking it own into steps and forcing the types! Got me a step closer for sure! (thus the upvote) I'm playing around with the debugging the PATH stuff  by resubmitting jobs on the CI to figure out the `install pnpm` with seems to be where I'm stuck now. Sadly DevOps team doesn't give me access with the Windows runner, so it's kind of taking shots in the dark. After I figure the next road block. I'll post back and formally accept the answer.

Comment: @EricD.Johnson You can echo out your PATH in PowerShell by leaving `$Env:PATH` on its own line which will output the contents of the environment variable to `stdout`.

Comment: Cool, I'll give that exact thing a try.

Comment: Thanks again @theincorrigible1 for your step by step explanation that even a n00b could follow along with. Sorry for being sassy earlier. In the end we couldn't use pnpm because it doesn't play nice with [Angular cli 6](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/1260#issuecomment-436103094) but if we upgrade to NG CLI 7 I will try this again.

Comment: @EricD.Johnson Sorry it didn't work with your toolset, but I'm glad my post was informative and helpful.  Sorry I was harsh earlier, but the volume of "do work for me" posts on SO is high.  Any work shown is better than no work.